# building jenkins docker image from official Dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerhub

I am trying to build a jenkins docker image from official jenkins git repo:
`https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker`.

But when I try to run the container of the image using `docker run -it -dP jenkins`, it exits immediately and when i check the docker logs, I get the following error:

```
: invalid option
```

I read that the error could be because the pid of tini is not 1. I looked at the documents and saw that if we do the following, it should solve the issue.
    Passing the -s argument to Tini (tini -s -- ...)
    Setting the environment variable TINI_SUBREAPER (e.g. export TINI_SUBREAPER=).

But it did not solve anything.

The following is the exact copy of the Dockerfile being built with `docker build -t jenkins .`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ARG user=jenkins
ARG group=jenkins
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000
ARG http_port=8080
ARG agent_port=50000

ENV JENKINS_HOME /var/jenkins_home
ENV JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT ${agent_port}
ENV TINI_SUBREAPER=

# Jenkins is run with user `jenkins`, uid = 1000
# If you bind mount a volume from the host or a data container,
# ensure you use the same uid
RUN groupadd -g ${gid} ${group} \
    && useradd -d "$JENKINS_HOME" -u ${uid} -g ${gid} -m -s /bin/bash ${user}

# Jenkins home directory is a volume, so configuration and build history
# can be persisted and survive image upgrades
VOLUME /var/jenkins_home

# `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/` contains all reference configuration we want
# to set on a fresh new installation. Use it to bundle additional plugins
# or config file with your custom jenkins Docker image.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d

ENV TINI_VERSION 0.14.0
ENV TINI_SHA 6c41ec7d33e857d4779f14d9c74924cab0c7973485d2972419a3b7c7620ff5fd

# Use tini as subreaper in Docker container to adopt zombie processes
RUN curl -fsSL https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/v${TINI_VERSION}/tini-static-amd64 -o /bin/tini && chmod +x /bin/tini \
  && echo "$TINI_SHA  /bin/tini" | sha256sum -c -

COPY init.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/tcp-slave-agent-port.groovy

# jenkins version being bundled in this docker image
ARG JENKINS_VERSION
ENV JENKINS_VERSION ${JENKINS_VERSION:-2.60.1}

# jenkins.war checksum, download will be validated using it
ARG JENKINS_SHA=34fde424dde0e050738f5ad1e316d54f741c237bd380bd663a07f96147bb1390

# Can be used to customize where jenkins.war get downloaded from
ARG JENKINS_URL=https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/jenkins-war/${JENKINS_VERSION}/jenkins-war-${JENKINS_VERSION}.war

# could use ADD but this one does not check Last-Modified header neither does it allow to control checksum
# see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8331
RUN curl -fsSL ${JENKINS_URL} -k -o /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war \
  && echo "${JENKINS_SHA}  /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war" | sha256sum -c -

ENV JENKINS_UC https://updates.jenkins.io
RUN chown -R ${user} "$JENKINS_HOME" /usr/share/jenkins/ref


# for main web interface:
EXPOSE ${http_port}

# will be used by attached slave agents:
EXPOSE ${agent_port}

ENV COPY_REFERENCE_FILE_LOG $JENKINS_HOME/copy_reference_file.log

USER ${user}

COPY jenkins-support /usr/local/bin/jenkins-support
COPY jenkins.sh /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]


# from a derived Dockerfile, can use `RUN plugins.sh active.txt` to setup /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins from a support bundle
COPY plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh
COPY install-plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh
```

Comment: How did you build the image? How did you try to run it?

Comment: used the standard docker command to build
`docker build -t jenkins .`
the docker run -it -dP jenkins

Comment: The example works for me. Can you clarify the Docker version and what host you are running on?

Comment: Docker version 1.12.5, build 7392c3b and RHEL 7

Comment: turns out my docker version did not build it properly, when I updated the docker, it worked for me. thanks!

Comment: please add/accept that answer accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the docker version. My Docker version was old. Not sure which command was not supported, but the new docker built the dockerfile.